# Opening a text file from a list to put through for loop

Tags: python

I have a folder of a few hundred text files with each one containing a couple rows of data that I need to condense. I want to open one file, grab two lines from that file, and combine those two lines into another text file I've created, then close the data file and repeat for the next.

I've started by creating a list of the directory. The problem I run into is trying to do a for loop to each file in the directory. It seems that the for loop is attempting to open the whole list instead of each item in the list. I'm fairly new to this and I'd be open to alternate solutions.

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir('/colors')
file = [filelist]
mylines = []

for x in file:
    with open('/colors/'+x, 'rt') as myfile: #opens single txt file for reading text as myfile
        for myline in myfile: #Creates list from each line of the txt file and puts it into myline
            mylines.append(myline.rstrip('\n')) #removes the paragraph space in list
        tup = (mylines[1], mylines[3]) #combines second and fourth line into one line into a tuple
    str = ''.join(tup) #joins the tuple into a string with no space between the two

print(str)
myfile.close()

f = open("textfile.txt","a")
f.write(str+'\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: `filelist` is already a `list` of filenames, then the code wraps it in yet another `list`. Try printing `filelist`, the issue should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that `os.listdir('/colors')` returns a list. You then put the list `filelist` inside another list named `file`. If the contents of your directory are

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

then you get the following:

```
filelist = os.listdir('/colors') # ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
file = [filelist]                # [['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']]
```

File is a list, with only one item, the list `filelist`.

If instead you use the following snippet, it should probably work.

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir('/colors')
mylines = []

for x in filelist:
#etc...
```